# TextureMapObject is not shown on isometric Tiled Map

Tags: libgdx

In my code I'm using the following code to load the .tmx map. I also use IsometricTiledMapRenderer. 
I would like to add a unit upon touch event on tile.

```
assetManager.setLoader(TiledMap.class, new TmxMapLoader(new InternalFileHandleResolver()));
        assetManager.load("maps/grass_and_water.tmx", TiledMap.class);
        assetManager.finishLoading();

        map = assetManager.get("maps/grass_and_water.tmx");

        renderer = new IsometricTiledMapRenderer(map, 1f / 64f);

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new GestureDetector(new MapGestureListener(camera, jetFlyingSprite, map)));`
```

In the touchDown I'm trying to add TextureMapObject on click.

```
 @Override
public boolean touchDown(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
    Gdx.app.log(TAG, "touchDown gesture");
    flinging = false;
    scale = camera.zoom;
    //return false;

    Vector3 clickCoordinates = new Vector3(x,y,0);
    Vector3 position = camera.unproject(clickCoordinates);

    Texture texture = new Texture("jet_flying.png");
    TextureRegion textureRegion = new TextureRegion(texture,400,400);

    MapLayer mapLayer =  map.getLayers().get("objects");
    mapLayer.setVisible(true);

    TextureMapObject textureMapObject = new TextureMapObject(textureRegion);
    textureMapObject.setName("plane");
    textureMapObject.setX((float)position.x);
    textureMapObject.setY((float)position.y);
    mapLayer.getObjects().add(textureMapObject);

    textureMapObject.setX((float)position.x);
    textureMapObject.setY((float)position.y);

    return true;
}
```

When running nothing happens when I click.

Any clues/?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing your `"objects"` layer is a Object layer, the implementation of that is left blank in `BatchTiledMapRenderer` which `IsometricTiledMapRenderer` inherits from. This means object layers are rendered.

[BatchTiledMapRenderer `renderMapLayer` method](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/maps/tiled/renderers/BatchTiledMapRenderer.java#L155) which calls [`renderObject`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/maps/tiled/renderers/BatchTiledMapRenderer.java#L183) which looks like this:

```
@Override
public void renderObject (MapObject object) {

}
```

You could subclass `IsometricTiledMapRenderer` and implement `renderObject` yourself.